# Are there events when an update is deployed through Appflow?

Tags: ionic-v1

I am trying to initiate a popup modal when the download is fully finished and extracted (the app is ready to be closed and reopened to enable the update.)

Are there events that can be listened to in order to initiate the popup at the time I’m wanting? Something like:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

 document.addEventListener("extracted", updateReady, false);

 function updateReady() {

    // Initiate popup here

 }
}
```